# Rails and FullCalendar - Query database with different column names

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I am currently using Rails 4.0 and FullCalendar.  My problem is: some of the fields in my database correspond differently with those of the FullCalendar defaults.  For example:

```
  My columns                         FullCalendar's Naming
================                   =========================
   all_day                                 allDay
   title                                   name
   start_time                              start
   end_time                                end
```

And here is my javascript (shortened):

```
 ...
 eventSources: [{
            url: '/calendar/index',
        }],
 ...
```

And my controller:

```
def index
@events = Event.all
respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @events }
    end
end
```

Do I need to change my query to something like `@events = Event.all(:all_day :as :allDay)`

I'm not quite sure how I should accomplish this.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just cook proper json (with `jbuilder` gem) like in demo http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/json-events.php 
Then implement it like it made in script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            editable: true,

            events: "json-events.php",

            eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
                alert(event.title + ' was moved ' + delta + ' days\n' +
                    '(should probably update your database)');
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            }

        });

    });
```

On the same page http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/json.html 
Then edit on your needs.
Wish it helps

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up using the FullCalendar `eventSources` method, e.g.,

```
eventSources: [{
        url: '/calendar/index'
    }],
```

And then, in my model, I simply defined the output in JSON:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base    
     def as_json(options = {})
       {
       :id => self.id,
       :title => self.name,
       :location => self.location,
       :details => self.details,
       :start => start_time.rfc822,
       :end => end_time.rfc822,
       :event_creator => user.full_name
       }
     end
end
```

And this seemed to do the trick for me!